# How to get the username from a field which is defined as "Name (with presence)"

Tags: xslt

In a custom list there is a column / field defined as “Name (with presence)”.

In my modified aspx page, I want to do an **‘xsl if’** statement to check if the value from this field is the same as the current user.

```
<xsl:if test="@MyField = $UserID">
    ... code here ...
</xsl:if>
```

But the compare fails because the content from the MyField is something like :

```
 <span>
           <A HREF="/sites/121579/MySite/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=452">***, Stef</A>
           <img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"/>
           <a href='javascript:' onclick='IMNImageOnClick();return false;' class='ms-imnlink'>
                  <img name='imnmark' title='' border='0' height='12' width='12' src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' alt='No presence information' sip='stef.***@***.com' id='imn_998,type=smtp'/>
           </a>
    </span>
```

And not just “***, Stef”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is very simple.

Don’t do test on 'equals'

```
<xsl:if test="@MyField = $UserID">
    ... things here ...
</xsl:if>
```

But a test on 'contains' (Just check if the field ‘MyField’ contains the value from $UserID)

```
<xsl:if test="contains(@MyField, $UserID)">
    ... things here ...
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: You could get a false positive this way. Since the UserID contained in the field is an integer, the first user in the UserInfo list will pass this test on anyone with a 1 in the ID. You could include the 'userdisp.aspx?ID=' and '&quot;' before an after the $UserID to eliminate this problem.

Comment: On my page, $UserId is defined as : <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
And it's represented as 'Lastname, Firstname', so the contains() function will work correct.

Comment: This is nice.  Very simple and easy solution.